# PIL (Pillow) getsize_multiline() in while loop going into infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Why would these few lines of codes go into an infinite loop? This seems to be the only possible part that's wrong with my code, since on commenting this out everything else works perfectly fine.

```
#Increase the font size till the text is just a little too wide
while selected_font.getsize_multiline(beautiful_text)[0] < (0.8 * img.size[0]):
    selected_font.size += 2

#If the text is too long, reduce the font size a little...
while selected_font.getsize_multiline(beautiful_text)[1] > (0.7 * img.size[1]):
    selected_font.size -= 2
    #..and then increase the number of characters per line till it's wide enough...
    while selected_font.getsize_multiline(beautiful_text)[0] < (0.8 * img.size[0]):
        wrapper.width += 2
        beautiful_text = wrapper.fill(input_text)
    #...rewrap the text, test again, and keep repeating till it sits well
```

I know that `selected_font.getsize_multiline(beautiful_text)` is a valid call which returns a tuple and the same goes for `img.size`. Upon increasing font size the width of the text box would definitely go up so why does this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: I suggest that you follow the steps outlined in this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . If that doesn't find the problem for you, it will at least put you in a position to ask a more focused question.

Comment: @TurePålsson Thanks for your advice, I have edited my post accordingly

Comment: You still have 3 'while' loops, each of which could potentially run amok. Have you checked which one it is? Have you looked at the return values from getsize_multiline and checked that they behave as you expect them to?

Comment: @TurePålsson As far as I can tell, two of them are infinite. I start with fontsize fairly small, so if I bypass the first loop, the text isn't even large enough to enter the second one. When I hardcode it to start at a huge font, then it gets stuck in the second loop, but only when the text is quite long, leading me to believe it's the first outer loop, and the internal while loop, that are potentially infinite.

Comment: And what about the returned values from getsize_multiline? Do they behave as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug. The problem lies in the fact that the font object returned by `ImageFont.truetype('fontfile', size = desired_size)`
(in this case the object `selected_font`) has a size attribute which is immutable.

```
selected_font = ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', size = 20)
print(selected_font.size)       #output: 20
selected_font.size = 10         #doesn't raise an error
print(selected_font.size)       #output: 20
```

and thus this line doesn't update the variable I'm checking against in the loop

```
selected_font.size += 2         #does nothing, and raises no errors
```

To add to the confusion, the TextWrapper module does have mutable size attribute for its line width
variable

```
wrapper.width += 5              #works as you'd expect
```

Either way, I solved my problem with this code

```
fontsize = 10

while selected_font.getsize_multiline(beautiful_text)[1] > (0.7 * img.size[1]):
    fontsize -= 2
    selected_font = ImageFont.truetype("src/CaviarDreams.ttf", size = fontsize)
```

and so on for the other loops as well.